# Clicking button using Apple Script

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to add some details to an UI application from an Apple script.
But i cannot click the "New" button in UI from script.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
    --click button 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1
    click button "New" of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1
end tell
```

[image: mstsc]

Accessibility Inspector

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use "New" for the *button's* `name` because the *value* for the `name` *property* of `button 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Microsoft Remote Desktop"` is `missing value`.

However, the *value* for the `description` *property* is `New`, so the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```
activate application "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
    click (every button of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 whose description is "New")
end tell
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *commands* may need to be adjusted for your system, and or additional `delay` *commands* may or may not be needed. Adjust *values* of and or add/remove the `delay` *commands* as appropriate.

You can use the following *example line of code* to get the *properties* of `button 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1` if **Microsoft Remote Desktop** is already running with just the main window open:

```
tell application "System Events" to get properties of button 1 of group 1 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Microsoft Remote Desktop"
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.